# PowerShell Script to move folders from A to B based on names

Tags: powershell, scripting, move, directory

Im looking for a PS script that will move a folder and/or folders with a specific string in the folder name (in this case S0) to another folder containing something specific (in this case (-= Shows)

Example:

ThatonefunnyshowS01E01
ThatonefunnyshowS01E02
ThatonefunnyshowS01E03
ThatonefunnyshowS01E04

I would like the PS script to "scan" the S:\ on my PC and move all folders with S0 into the directory below. If it cant scan, I can run it from the specific directory where they live and that will work too.

The paths are

Source is S:\ -= Downloads\
Destination is S:\ -= Shows\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem S:\Downloads\*S0* | Move-Item -Destination S:\Shows
```

Comment: You can use the `-WhatIf` parameter on Move-Item to see what it would do before committing to making the moves.  :-)

Comment: It doesnt like the move-item command:                                                                                                                               Move-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take
 pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It needed the -Destination parameter.

Comment: @Rico are you referring to the answer itself, or the comment?

Comment: @TimFerrill never mind, this answer was flagged as low quality by SO, but it looks like it's the right answer.